# What is the best manner to run many Scrapy with multiprocessing?

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, scrapy, multiprocessing

currently I use Scrapy with multiprocessing. I made a POC, in order to run many spider.
My code look like that:

```
#!/usr/bin/python 
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from multiprocessing import Lock, Process, Queue, current_process

def worker(work_queue, done_queue):
    try:
        for url in iter(work_queue.get, 'STOP'):
            status_code = run_spider(action)
    except Exception, e:
        done_queue.put("%s failed on %s with: %s" % (current_process().name, action, e.message))
    return True


def run_spider(action):
    os.system(action)

def main():
    sites = (
        scrapy crawl level1 -a url='https://www.example.com/test.html',
        scrapy crawl level1 -a url='https://www.example.com/test1.html',
        scrapy crawl level1 -a url='https://www.example.com/test2.html',
        scrapy crawl level1 -a url='https://www.example.com/test3.html',
        scrapy crawl level1 -a url='https://www.anotherexample.com/test4.html',
        scrapy crawl level1 -a url='https://www.anotherexample.com/test5.html',
        scrapy crawl level1 -a url='https://www.anotherexample.com/test6.html',
        scrapy crawl level1 -a url='https://www.anotherexample.com/test7.html',
        scrapy crawl level1 -a url='https://www.anotherexample.com/test8.html',
        scrapy crawl level1 -a url='https://www.anotherexample.com/test9.html',
        scrapy crawl level1 -a url='https://www.anotherexample.com/test10.html',
        scrapy crawl level1 -a url='https://www.anotherexample.com/test11.html',
    )

    workers = 2
    work_queue = Queue()
    done_queue = Queue()
    processes = []

    for action in sites:
        work_queue.put(action)

    for w in xrange(workers):
        p = Process(target=worker, args=(work_queue, done_queue))
        p.start()
        processes.append(p)
        work_queue.put('STOP')

    for p in processes:
        p.join()

    done_queue.put('STOP')

    for status in iter(done_queue.get, 'STOP'):
        print status

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

According you, what is the best solution to run multiple instance of Scrapy  ?

It would be better to launch a Scrapy instance for each URL or launch a spider with x URL (ex: 1 spider with 100 links) ?

Answer (score 0):

> It would be better to launch a Scrapy instance for each URL or launch a spider with x URL (ex: 1 spider with 100 links) ?

Launching an instance of Scrapy is definitely a bad choice, because for every URL you would be suffering from the overhead of Scrapy itself.

I think it would be best to distribute URLs evenly across spiders.